# Jquery daynamic id select issue

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am trying to flip a content dynamically, Here my html content

```
<div id="card<?php echo $employees->id; ?>" class="card">
       <div class="front">
             //content for front              
       </div>
       <div class="back">
            //content for back
       </div>
 </div>
```

I have used a jquery flip plugin.It's working fine, but here I need to make it dynamic. For that I have tried below code

```
    $('.card').mouseenter(function(){
                var card_id = $(this).attr('id');
                //alert(card_id);

                $(this).attr('id').flip({
                    axis: "x", // y or x
                    reverse: false, // true and false
                    trigger: "hover", // click or hover
                    speed: 500
               }); 
 });
```

It's not working, But if I try it for single div,it's working.

```
$("#card2").flip({
                axis: "x", // y or x
                reverse: false, // true and false
                trigger: "hover", // click or hover
                speed: 500
 });  //it's working
```

How I can make it dynamic for all content in jquery selector  ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".card").each(function(i) {
        $this = $(this).attr('id', "card" + (i + 1));
        $this.flip({
            axis: "x", // y or x
            reverse: false, // true and false
            trigger: "hover", // click or hover
            speed: 500
        });
    });
});​
```

Comment: what is the logic behind `id` value change. Will you please elaborate it and let us know why it is working after id change?

Answer (score 1):

Try this : You are calling `.flip()` on `$(this).attr('id')` which returns id and not jquery object. Call function on `$(this)` as shown below.

```
$('.card').mouseenter(function(){
                var card_id = $(this).attr('id');
                //alert(card_id);

                $(this).flip({
                    axis: "x", // y or x
                    reverse: false, // true and false
                    trigger: "hover", // click or hover
                    speed: 500
               }); 
 });
```

Comment: It's working ! But I need to mouse enter two times. May you told me what is the cause ?

Answer (score 1):

Just call `$(this).flip({`

you don't need to use `.attr`

---

you need to call `.flip` on jquery object and not on an id attribute.